# Forgot to turn on RAID after flashing bios, now have, but can't boot

Tags: windows-7, raid, intel-rst

I was having BSOD issues with my Windows 7, RAID 1 (Intel RST) machine and so decided to flash to the newest Asus BIOS. I think that part went well, but when reconfiguring the BIOS I neglected to change the data storage setting from IDE to RAID (at least those are the terms I remember). In the boot device menu, I selected one of the two hard drives that normally are the RAID array, which didn't seem right, but anyway that's what I did. It booted to Windows 7, and showed a dialog that was installing drivers for the hard drive and listing them separately. I went oops, and then noticed that Intel RST was offline.

Recalling the BIOS setting that I'd skipped, I went back to the BIOS and set SATA to RAID and boot device to that RAID. Now it won't boot and I get this boot screen.

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \Boot\BCD
```

How do I back out of this error?

Comment: This is what the Windows 7 [startup repair](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-are-system-recovery-options#what-are-system-recovery-options=windows-7) system recovery option is for.

Comment: Start Repair failed...I'd already tried it. I am going to try to recover the mbr, since that seems to have fixed this kind of issue for others. Does that sound sensible?

Comment: Can you describe how it failed?

Comment: Boot with windows dvd
Choose Repair
System recovery options does "searching for windows installations
Then, windows found problems with your computer's startup options. 
Detail shows bootmgr will be repaired
Then "Failed to save startup options"
Then "re-image your computer" with "attach last of backup set etc"

Comment: ahhh...this software...superuser...
Boot with windows dvd
Choose Repair
System recovery options does "searching for windows installations
Then, windows found problems with your computer's startup options. 
Detail shows bootmgr will be repaired
Then "Failed to save startup options"
Then "re-image your computer" with "attach last of backup set etc" which I don't have.

Comment: If you were getting BSoDs before you flashed the BIOS, you probably have other pre-existing problems that you've potentially now made worse.  Do as it says: "attach last of backup set etc" and "re-image your computer". If you have no backup, then recover as much data as possible and reinstall Windows.

Comment: What? There is no way to recover the ability to boot from this raid array? It shows as a raid array, needs to be verified. 

Even if it was impossible to recover from this raid issue, I am pretty sure I can still boot to either of the disks if I turn off raid in the bios and just use them as sata ide.

Flashing the bios to the current version was an attempt to solve the bsod issue. I tried many other things first.

Comment: I just made an experiment (didn't execute at the end point). I changed sata in bios to IDE, booted to windows dvd, asked it to repair, and it recovered the two hdd both as windows 7 pro. I am not going to actually let the windows boot manager go with either recovered hdd at this time...I still think there is a way to get the raid back up. I'll wait for more input.

Comment: It is a "driver" issue, when the bios is set into other modes Raid Achi ide , a driver is tossed on and it flat out crashes. You can re-install in that mode, or you have to mess with the drivers , by turning off , and you also need to have installed a correct driver .  I actually pulled it off via the GUI once, but i did it more by accident http://www.overclock.net/t/1227636/how-to-change-sata-modes-after-windows-7-installation